# replace url parameter and text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

When I click search button the url parameter is taking care of. I need to change that url parameter name and value using jquery.

per example: search button clicked

```
http://testsite/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=deana&cs=This%20Site
```

Replace with:

```
 http://testsite/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=deana&s=All%20Sites
```

I can not modify search button functionality, because it is out of the box functionality.

I can do changing url parameter and value. How can we do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing the parameter of a URL should be fairly straightfoward:

```
var param = window.location.href;
var param_q = param.split('?');
var param_ampersand = param_q[1].split('&');
var param_eq_1 = param_ampersand[0].split('=');
var param_eq_2 = param_ampersand[1].split('=');
var new_param_name_1 = 'test';
var new_param_value_1 = 'example';
var new_param_name_2 = 'test2';
var new_param_value_2 = 'example2';
// avoid infinite loop
if ((param_eq_1[0] != new_param_name_1 || param_eq_1[1] != new_param_value_1) || (param_eq_2[0] != new_param_name_2 || param_eq_2[1] != new_param_value_2)) window.location = param_q[0] + '?' + new_param_name_1 + '=' + new_param_value_1 + '&' + new_param_name_2 + '=' + new_param_value_2;
```

This worked for me in Chrome/FF. This just redirects the parameter - not sure if this is what you're looking for.

**EDIT**:

Added a logic to handle two parameters.

Comment: But I need to change parameter name too.

Comment: @James123 - changing the value of new_param_1 will change the parameter name. Is that what you need or am I misunderstanding? It will redirect http://test.com?some=value to http://test.com?test=example.